# Get Array Value Php

Tags: arrays

I have simple array like this..

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [owner] => Michael Sam Groud [jud_project] => Gardening Stone [url_page] => http://www.abcd.com [url_gambar] => Array ( [0] => http://abcd.com/blog/cg34678859-5677/traditional-hall.jpg, http://abcd.com/blog/cg34678859-5679/traditional-living-room.jpg, ) ) )
```

So, i want to get value from that array..

```
owner = Michael Sam Groud 
jud_project = Gardening Stone
url_page = http://www.abcd.com
url_gambar = http://abcd.com/blog/cg34678859..
```

As far as i try it my own code it just give me strange result...

```
echo $arr [0]["owner"];
```

The result just

```
A
```

Comment: what about `echo $arr["owner"];`?

Comment: i was try it... stil can't....
The result... Undefined index

Comment: `foreach($arr as $real){
  echo $real["owner"];
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try put all together, like:

```
echo $arr[0]['owner'];
```

use `var_dump()` or `print_r()`, to see what's wrong with your array if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code.  There's nothing wrong here but you've clearly got a syntax error in the real thing.  As you've presented it, everything should work:

```
$arr = Array (
 '0' => Array (
  'owner' => 'Michael Sam Groud',
  'jud_project' => 'Gardening Stone',
  'url_page' => 'http://www.abcd.com',
  'url_gambar' => Array (
   '0' => 'http://abcd.com/blog/cg34678859-5677/traditional-hall.jpg, http://abcd.com/blog/cg34678859-5679/traditional-living-room.jpg'
  )
 )
);

echo $arr[0]['owner'];

Michael Sam Groud
```

Answer (score 0):

i supposed u have somthing like that:

```
$array = array("owner" => "Michael Sam Groud",  
          "jud_project" => "Gardening Stone",
          "url_page" => "http://www.abcd.com",
          "url_gambar" => array ("http://abcd.com/blog/cg34678859-5677/traditional-hall.jpg", "http://abcd.com/blog/cg34678859-5679/traditional-living-room.jpg")
          );

print_r($array);
```

you must be doing like

```
echo $array["owner"];
```

or with json

```
$json = json_encode($array);

$json = json_decode($json, true);

echo $json["owner"];
```

check your version of php or verify the format of array

Comment: Yes my array like that.. not different...

But i dont know, your code not work too.. Stil the result just A